# Form Function Call Malfunction

Tags: vba, ms-access

First some definitions:

- Access Program Name: ATS
- Web tool name: C360

---

C360 doesn't always display readystate indicators in a timely fashion, so ATS is set to time out after five seconds to ask the user what to do next (Error 100).  I'm using a form as a message box to allow for better formatting. This button (code below) is what the user presses to capture the data displayed in C360, despite not being in readystate.

I have two forms, one called Basic Ticksheet and one called Advanced Ticksheet (some of my users are a bit overstimulated if presented with too much information) that run the same functions, but display the data differently. Basic and Advanced cannot be open at the same time or read-write errors occur. As such, when Error 100 occurs, and the user presses this button, it is supposed to run the advanced code first, and if an error occurs, re-route to the basic code.

I cannot figure out why Error 2450 ('Microsoft Access Cannot find the referenced form 'Advanced Ticksheet') is firing when the user is using Basic Ticksheet. The code works flawlessly when I manually step through line-by-line. When I press 'Debug' it highlights the line beginning with: Call forms ("Basic Ticksheet"). If I step through using Debug, it also works flawlessly.

**What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to accomplish this?**

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer!

```
Private Sub BTN_CaptureCase_Click()
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "Alert Error 100", acSaveYes

Advanced_Ticksheet:
    On Error GoTo Basic_Ticksheet
        Call Forms("Advanced Ticksheet").Controls("Primary_Review").Form.BTN_CaptureCaseWithWM_Click
    Exit Sub

Basic_Ticksheet:
    Call Forms("Basic Ticksheet").Controls("BasicCapture").Form.BTN_CaptureCaseWithWM_Click

End Sub
```

The BTN_CaptureCaseWithWM_Click code is as follows (which calls additional code that is also marked as public):

```
Sub BTN_CaptureCaseWithWM_Click()
        CaptureC360CaseData
        ExtractCaseDetails
        WMTFrameClick
        ExtractWMTDetails
End Sub
```

Comment: Try changing Private to Public.

Comment: Hi June7, Do you mean in the code shown above or for the call fo the respective BTN_CaptureCaseWithWM? If talking about the call, each of these are public already [added their code to the above query]

Comment: I mean the procedure declaration in the posted code. It's the only place I see the word 'Private'.

Comment: @June7,removing the word 'private' is not the solution, unfortunately. I broke out the code to individual modules and it's actually generating an error 2046 "Refresh Record isn't Available Now" (Refresh Record is part of the procedure in the call. Ironically, when I attempt to debug, it works perfectly.

Comment: Sorry, did not thoroughly read question and cannot help with web issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this was as simple as the form containing the function wasn't actually the focus. Totally beating myself up over it, too!

I added a line to ensure the correct form was the focus before calling the code in the form. Of course, I also tooled the flow to make it work better, in the process.

> Sub BTN_CaptureCase_Click()
>       DoCmd.Close acForm, "Alert Error 100", acSaveYes
>
> ```
> If CurrentProject.AllForms("Basic Ticksheet").IsLoaded Then
>     Forms("Basic Ticksheet").SetFocus
>     Call Forms("Basic Ticksheet").Controls("BasicCapture").Form.BTN_CaptureCaseWithWM_Click
>     Application.Echo True
>     ElseIf CurrentProject.AllForms("Advanced Ticksheet").IsLoaded Then
>         Forms("Advanced Ticksheet").SetFocus
>         Call Forms("Advanced Ticksheet").Controls("Primary_Review").Form.BTN_CaptureCaseWithWM_Click
>         Application.Echo True
>         ElseIf CurrentProject.AllForms("Super Basic Ticksheet").IsLoaded Then
>             Forms("Super Basic Ticksheet").SetFocus
>             Call Forms("Super Basic Ticksheet").Controls("SuperBasicCapture").Form.BTN_CaptureCaseWithWM_Click
>             Application.Echo True
>             Else: MsgBox "Error 100 routing failure. Please notify ATS Administrator!"
> End If
> ```